# finding the Ker(T)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:\mathcal P_2(\Bbb R)\rightarrow \Bbb R^2$ be the linear transformation defined by

$T (p(x))=[p(0),p(1)]$

Find a basis for Ker(T)?

I actually know how to find ker(T) once it becomes the standard matrix, I am just confused about the following: I was thinking that firstly, take any polynominal saying $p(x)=x^2+bx+c$, so $p(0)=c, p(1)=1+b+c$, then $T (p(x))=[c,1+b+c]$, but then I get stucked?

Comment: So you know that for $T(p(x))$ to be $[0,0]$, you need $c=0$; but do note that an element of $\mathcal{P}_2(\mathbb{R})$ is not necessarily monic. So why do you think $p(x)=x^2+bx+c$, and not $ax^2+bx+c$ ?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I know it is not monic, I was on the wrong direction???

Comment: You were on the right track, but why did you take a monic polynomial? You should have $[c,a+b+c]$, and figure out what you need for this to be the zero vector.

Comment: I guess I understand what you are saying. Then  using T(a,b,c)=[c, a+b+c] to find the standard matrx??

Comment: You don’t need to find the standard matrix. What conditions do you need on $a$, $b$, and $c$, for this vector to be equal to $[0,0]$? Once you have those conditions, you have the description of the polynomials that map to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $T$ is surjective since for every $(x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2$ for the polynomial $p(t) = (y-x)t+x$ we have
$$Tp= (p(0), p(1))=(x,y).$$

Therefore by the rank-nullity theorem we have
$$3 = \dim \mathcal{P}_2(\Bbb{R}) = \dim\ker T + \dim \operatorname{Im} T = \dim\ker T + \dim \Bbb{R}^2 = \dim\ker T + 2$$
so $\dim\ker T$ is one-dimensional.

Hence for the basis we only need one polynomial $p$ of degree $\le 2$ such that $p(0)=p(1) = 0$. The simplest example is
$$p(t) = t^2-t$$
so a basis for $\ker T$ is $\{p\}$.

Answer (score 0):

The kernel is the following subset of $\mathcal{P}_2(\mathbb{R})$:
$$\{p \in \mathcal{P}_2(\mathbb{R}): T(p) = [0\; 0]\}.$$

Thus, $p \in \ker T \iff p(0) = p(1) = 0$.

---

In other words, the kernel consists precisely of those degree $\le 2$ polynomials which have $0$ and $1$ as roots. This means that the polynomial must be of the form
$$a(x - 0)(x - 1) = a(x^2 - x).$$

Thus, a basis for the kernel is $\{x^2 - x\}.$

Comment: thanks for sharing your thought. I am not sure if I understand your answer, the way we taught is kind of different from yours, then what is the span and dimension according to your answer?

Comment: @user781604: the dimension (of the kernel) is going to be 1. This is precisely because my basis has 1 element and dimension is simply the cardinality of any basis. I'm not sure what you mean by "span". Span of what? The kernel? That would not make sense. The span of my basis? That would precisely be the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, then 
$$T(p(x))=\begin{bmatrix}c \\ a+b+c\end{bmatrix}.$$
If $p(x) \in \ker(T)$, then $T(p(x))=\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$. So we get
\begin{align*}
a+b+c & = 0\\
c& =0.
\end{align*}
This gives us $a=-b$ and $c=0$. Thus 
$$\ker(T)=\{a(x^2-x) \, | \, a \in \mathbb{R}\}.$$
A basis for $\ker(T)$ is $\{x^2-x\}$.